# Creating property which may throw IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, api-design

I have a class containing a collection of items.  For convenience I've provided GetCurrentItem which is implemented by

```
public Type GetCurrentItem
{
     get { return this.items[this.items.Count - 1]; }  
}
```

which will throw an exception if there are no items in the list.

Should I let the exception be thrown or should I return `null`?  If this was an API I handed to you, what would you expect? The exception or null?  Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Which is the correct API:  `Enumerable.Single` or `Enumerable.SingleOrDefault`?   (answer: it depends)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As to which is more correct?  As Kirk's comment suggests: it depends.  Sometimes a `null` makes logical sense and sometimes an exception is better suited if no default is reasonable.  One thing I try to do is think of "is calling `GetCurrentItem` a logical failure or a safe thing?"

If it is a failure to call `GetCurrentItem` when there are none, then throwing an exception is the correct course.  For example, if your collection has a `HasCurrent` or `IsEmpty` property where someone could examine the result before calling `GetCurrentItem`, then they should "know better".  But if the current item is `null` is a correct logical way of using your class, then by all means design it that way.  Either way, I'd document the behavior in the code comments to let users know of expected behavior.

I will say this though, exposing the `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception may be bleeding implementation details.  That is, if the user of this class has no idea that the inner structure is an array or `List<T>`, then don't bleed out that exception, but catch it, wrap it, and throw a more meaningful one (custom, or something like `InvalidOperationException`).

Since they're not really directly passing in an argument, them getting an `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception could be confusing :-)

Comment: A good choice of exception is `InvalidOperationException`, following the example set by `Stack<T>.Peek()`.

Comment: @MichaelLiu: Yep, agree.  I was adding that in my edit just as you commented :-)

Answer (score 3):

Let it throw an error.  This is just how other collections work.  It should be up to the user application to handle potential exceptions (especially when working with collections).  There should maybe be a `bool HasSelection()` method which the user can call before proceeding.

Answer (score 3):

Exceptions should be used for exceptional cases. If CurrentItem can be null you shouldn't throw an exception. I don't see why not having a CurrentItem is exceptional.

Answer (score 1):

The question then is whether you expect GetCurrentItem to return a safe value. If Type is nullable, then GetCurrentItem should probably return null when there is no current item. If you always expect the list to be non-empty and for there to always be something selected by default, then throw a meaningful exception.

You generally shouldn't throw an exception unless your case really is an exception and not a normal use case. However, this can be rather subjective.

Answer (score 1):

I try to think about it from a user's perspective. Go for the [Principal of Least Astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

If I was using the library or object and called `GetCurrentItem` and an `IndexOutOfRangeException` was thrown, I would think, "I didn't call anything with an index, I wanted the current item." Therefore, my suggestion would be to return null, which would make me think, "Oh, there is no current item."

Alternatively, if the property were an indexer and I wanted to get an item at a certain index I would not be surprised by an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Answer (score 0):

If this GetCurrentItem makes sense for your API I would throw "InvalidOperationException" when there are no items. You may want to name it differently if allowing null as valid result.

Consider if existing [LINQ Last](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.last.aspx) method already provides the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, follow .NET. This functionality looks similar to List.Last(), which throws an exception if empty.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775